# How to sync mysql table fields with prefix

Tags: php, mysql, prefix, synchronize

I want ask that, is there any easy way to synchronize mysql table fields?
Let me extend my question:

I have a mysql database driven site, and I want to use my table for more than one content provider (I can use only one table because of hosting features) by separating table prefix (like Wordpress does).

I need a way to copy all fields from current table and add a prefix (I'll specify) to all new entries (E.g : there are 2 fields, links, pages and I want to add new fields new_links, new_pages to current table automatically / all keys must be the same (I mean field id's, values etc..)).

After creating those fields, there should be a way to control that, if one or more new entry was added to original fields then new fields should be created in prefixed (new_) fields.

Comment: Bad idea here. If you try and combine two different apps in one table your going to run into a giant mess with primary keys and inserting new records. Time to look to different hosting plan

Comment: @grantk This is not mine host, my customer and he doesn't want to buy new one. Actually this is not a huge database only one table & 10-15 entries.

Comment: I don't see a way of doing this given the hosting limitations. Specifically "if one or more new entry was added to original fields then new fields should be created in prefixed (new_)" might be do-able with a view or trigger, but if you can't create a new table, then you're very unlikely to be able to create a view/trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I'm getting the issue, but...

Adding two new columns to the table shouldn't be a problem:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN new_links ...
```

You could keep them in sync from your application (problematic) or via a trigger.

Definitely time to upgrade hosting providers.